# How to add automated kill switch to robot?

Tags: navigation, odometry, ros-kinetic, jackal, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My UGV sometimes behaves erratically when navigating autonomously with move_base. It will sometimes get caught in loops when performing turns to reach a nav goal, or it will completely lose it's pose and lose its pose wrt to the ground and think it's flipped in the air (as seen in rviz). When it is behaving erratically, it can even rush a wall and try to climb it until it tips over! I'd like to add a kill condition that will monitor its odometry, speed, and acceleration and send an interrupt to move_base to shut down when this happens. What's the best way of going about this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300496/how-to-add-automated-kill-switch-to-robot?/) by [asabet](https://answers.ros.org/users/35904/asabet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2018-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can cancel a navigation goal by publishing on the `/move_base/cancel` topic:

```
rostopic pub /move_base/cancel actionlib_msgs/GoalID -- {}
```

This will cancel all the navigation goals that are given and you dont need to kill and restart move_base. You can write a node that monitors the speed/odometry or acceleration and cancel the goal within it based on your custom logic.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1